# How to remove last directory from a path with sed?

Tags: shell, sed, path

How to remove the last dir with `sed` (not `dirname`), like this:

```
echo "/dir1/dir2/dir3/dir4" | sed .....
```

So I would get `/dir1/dir2/dir3`.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
sed 's,/*[^/]\+/*$,,'
```

If it's part of the shell script, then `dirname` will be definitely more clear.

Comment: This does not work if the directory has a "." (period) in its name

Comment: @ChrisF Huh? Why you wrote so? `echo a.b/c.d/e.f | sed 's,/*[^/]\+/*$,,'` returns `a.b/c.d` or it doesn't in your sed version? My regexp has nothing to do with `.` at all.

Comment: dirname has problems with "." in the dir name, the regex works fine.

Answer (score 38):

you don't have to use external tools

`$ a="/dir1/dir2/dir3/dir4"`

`$ echo ${a%/*}`

Comment: While the currently accepted answer is definitely good, I believe this one should be the accepted answer if the question pertains to bash. Bash parameter substitution just feels more "true" bash than sed.

Comment: It can't be used for streamed input, though.

Comment: @anuragw I think the syntax is POSIX shell, not exclusively BASH.

Comment: @zneak To determine the last directory, every stream has to end first. Then it's not a matter of stream, but solely a matter of size.

Answer (score 8):

you can use "dirname" shell command:

```
dirname /dir2/dir3/dir4
```

Answer (score 6):

```
echo "/etc1/etc2/etc3/etc" | sed -e "s/\/[^\/]*$//"
```

produces

```
/etc1/etc2/etc3
```

Basically strip off anything at the end after the last slash that doesn't contain another slash.

Comment: Oops, using commas as the delimiter like przemoc indicated would be better to avoid having to escape the slashes in the script, making it more readable.  I always make that mistake.